# Is it possible to use APCu with XAMPP on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, cache

I've spent two days trying to install it with my php5.5.15 on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. Just curious if anyone out there ever got it to work. If so, please help.

Comment: Same issue here, default package does not ship that extension